# How to change the background on all forms from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

```
 //when button is clicked
 this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"file_location");
```

Is there anyway i can make a Base class and change the file location for the

```
 this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"file_location");
```

on the forms i will be opening after so that depending on what image was choosen all forms would share the same background image

Comment: Why not simply loop all forms and set their background appropriately?

Comment: What about you initialize all your forms with a specified image and update them by using `foreach Form f in Application.OpenForms {f.BackgroundImage = ...}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change BackgroundImage for all forms in your app after button click, try this:

```
public class BaseForm: Form
{
  private static Bitmap _skin = new Bitmap(@"default");
  // base Form stores static image which should be set as background for derived forms
  public static Bitmap Skin 
  {
    get { return _skin; }
    set { _skin = value; OnSkinChanged(EventArgs.Empty); }
  }

  // when current image changes, event is raised
  static event EventHandler SkinChanged;

  static void OnSkinChanged(EventArgs e)
  {
    if (SkinChanged!=null)
        SkinChanged(null, e);
  }

  public BaseForm()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     // all derived forms are subscribed to event of changing background image
     // they update own background image
     BaseForm.SkinChanged += SetSkinHandler;

     // set background when form created
     if (!DesignMode) // do not change in design mode (optional check)
        SetSkin();     
  }

  private void SetSkinHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SetSkin();
  }

  private void SetSkin()
  {
    this.BackgroundImage = BaseForm.Skin;
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
        if (disposing)
        {
            BaseForm.SkinChanged -= SetSkinHandler;
        }
        // default
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

set image in button Click handler (somethere from settings menu)

```
private void SkinButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BaseForm.Skin = new Bitmap(@"file_location");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution : save color or path to image in some value.
And when opens some new form, pass this value as parameter in it's constructor. And after init set `BackgroundImage`.

In First Form :

```
var backGround = String.Empty;
private void SelectBackGround(){
//some stuff
   backGround = imgPath;
}

protected void btn_click(...){
   var form = new Form2(backGround);
   form.Show();
}
```

In Form2 :

```
public Form2(string img){
   //init controls
   this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(img);
}
```

Something like this...

Comment: If he actually uses this throughout his whole application, I like his idea of subclassing System.Windows.Form and use his own class as baseclass everywhere better. However i am not exactly sure what he is asking, since he basically posted this solution in his question already.